# Python: Numpy dtype U32 - simple if-else statement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I dont understand the following behavior of a numpy array. Given the following array f:

```
array([u'1.8', u'1.8', u'2.4', u'2.2', u'2.0', u'2.1', u'2.8', u'3.2',
       u'3.3', u'3.4', u'2.8'], dtype='<U32')

for a in f:
    if a > 2.2:
        print "greater"
    else:
        print "smaller"
```

The result is always greater.

Comment: Any reason why your array contains ``strings`` instead of ``numbers``?

Answer (score 4):

This is because the values in your `array` are Unicode strings, not integers. In `python`, a numeric type will always be "greater" than a non numeric type on comparison. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/5919154) for a more in depth explanation.

To get the functionality you intended you need to convert the strings to numbers.